# Galaxy S6 screen dimensions - android

Tags: android, screen

I use the below code to get the width of a Galaxy S6 screen in pixels

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
Log.i("INFO", "width pixels "+metrics.widthPixels);
```

On one app this returns 1440 which is correct as per Samsung.
On another app the same code returns 1080 ??

density also changes from 4 to 3 as well as xdpi 580 to 435

Any ideas why I'm getting two different results?
Both apps target the same SDK: 23 and min SDK: 10

Answer (score 1):

The different resolutions are caused by the `gameservice`on Samsung devices. You can check this by installing the [Samsung Game Tuner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.gametuner.thin&hl=en/) on the device and setting your application to full mode. AFAIK there's no programatic way to set the app to full mode.

Comment: See [How to tell whether Samsung Game Tuner is changing resolution ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38617750/199364) for a bit more information on what the second app must be seeing. However, this does not explain why the second app saw the adjusted (75%) resolution, while first app saw the raw (100%) resolution.