# How to tell whether Samsung Game Tuner is changing resolution ratio

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

As other posts have shown, Samsung's Game Tuner can silently change the resolution of your game, making drag and drop no longer function.

I have changed my app to check if Game Tuner is installed, but I would like to detect if it has changed the Resolution Ratio to <100%.

I logged standard and real DisplayMetrics for both 100% and 75% Resolution Ratio (see below). But there is no difference that I see I can use.

Does anybody have a clue what display metrick I might look at?

Resolution Ratio=100%
2016-07-27 06:59:02.534 
Standard display metrics
fontScalingFactor=4.000000, logicalDensity=4.000000, densityDPI=640, widthpx=1440, heightpx=2560
Real display metrics
fontScalingFactor=4.000000, logicalDensity=4.000000, densityDPI=640, widthpx=1440, heightpx=2560

Resolution Ratio=75%
2016-07-27 07:00:40.517 
Standard display metrics
fontScalingFactor=3.000000, logicalDensity=3.000000, densityDPI=480, widthpx=1080, heightpx=1920
Real display metrics
fontScalingFactor=3.000000, logicalDensity=3.000000, densityDPI=480, widthpx=1080, heightpx=1920